# Access of single gmail account to multiple users

Tags: email, imap, pop3, thunderbird

I want to give access to single gmail account to around 10 users but i would like to provide read-only access to the gmail account via Thunderbird client so that persons using it can only see the mails and not delete them. Issue with IMAP is that if one of the users delete the mail then it will get deleted for all the users. The issue with POP is that the only first user which access the mail can download the attachments.

Please suggest a suitable solution.

Comment: I know that if you let others read your email via the gmail settings there is an option to "Leave conversation as unread when opened by others"...you access this via "settings"->"accounts and import" and "grant access to your email"...not sure about read only access though sorry, I don't think it is possible..at least with my limited experience -  hope it helps

Comment: There is, as far as I know, no way to provide read-only access to an account.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in your case is to use POP3 access and set in all TB clients "leave messages on server for at most XXX days". You can change this option selecting your account in Account Treeview, then opening context menu and selecting "Settings..."; in the newly opened window select tab "Server Settings". You must be sure that the user not change this option once you've set. You can't set an access to TB client only in readonly mode (and if also you could do via add-on, a skilled user could easily bypass it).